# Send a burst/multi threaded requests using bash and curl

Tags: bash, curl

I have a use case where I want to send a burst of requests. My current script sends the request sequentially but I want to be able to send a burst of requests (all of them at once) and wait for the response to come back (ex. if I enter 10 as request count- all 10  should be sent together). I am not sure how I can achieve that using bash and curl. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

CURL="/usr/bin/curl"
echo -n "how many times you want to run the request: "
read erc
ERC="$erc"
#count=1;
total_connect=0
total_start=0
total_time=0
    echo " Time_Connect Time_startTransfer Time_total HTTP_Code ";
#while [ $count -le $ERC ]
for ((i=1;i<=$ERC;i+=1)); do
    result=`$CURL -k -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total}:%{http_code} -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Accept: text/xml" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept: application/cbor" "http://google.com"`
    echo $result;

    var=$(echo $result | awk -F":" '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}')
    set -- $var

    total_connect=`echo "scale=6; $total_connect + $1"  | bc`;
    total_start=`echo "scale=6; $total_start + $2" | bc`;
    total_time=`echo "scale=6; $total_time + $3" | bc`;
    #count=$((count+1))
done
echo "URL executed is http://google.com"
echo "HTTP CODE of all request is $4"
echo "average time connect: `echo "scale=6; $total_connect/$ERC" | bc`";
echo "average time start: `echo "scale=6; $total_start/$ERC" | bc`";
echo "average Totaltime taken: `echo "scale=6; $total_time/$ERC" | bc`";
```

Comment: The short answer is & and wait - I'll post an updated version of your code below.

Comment: Thanks Mark I tried that but it threw syntax errors for me. I will wait for your code though. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code with the `&` introduced to issue all of the curls "at the same time".

```
#!/bin/bash

CURL="/usr/bin/curl"
echo -n "how many times you want to run the request: "
read erc
ERC="$erc"
#count=1;
total_connect=0
total_start=0
total_time=0
    echo " Time_Connect Time_startTransfer Time_total HTTP_Code ";
#while [ $count -le $ERC ]
for ((i=1;i<=$ERC;i+=1)); do
  {
    result=`$CURL -k -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total}:%{http_code} -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Accept: text/xml" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept: application/cbor" "http://google.com"`
    echo $result;

    var=$(echo $result | awk -F":" '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}')
    set -- $var

    total_connect=`echo "scale=6; $total_connect + $1"  | bc`;
    total_start=`echo "scale=6; $total_start + $2" | bc`;
    total_time=`echo "scale=6; $total_time + $3" | bc`;
    #count=$((count+1))
  } > $i.result &
done
wait
# TODO:  You'll need to write code here to process the intermediate results in *.result
# It would have been helpful to have created a temporary directory for your indivdual results as well
echo "URL executed is http://google.com"
echo "HTTP CODE of all request is $4"   
echo "average time connect: `echo "scale=6; $total_connect/$ERC" | bc`";
echo "average time start: `echo "scale=6; $total_start/$ERC" | bc`";
echo "average Totaltime taken: `echo "scale=6; $total_time/$ERC" | bc`";
```

The `wait` I introduced tells bash to wait for all of the child processes (curls and such) to complete before continuing.

Comment: Thanks Mark I will give this a shot and test it out. Appreciate your help!!

Comment: to fix the broken .result I tried something like this var=$(echo $ERC.result | awk -F":" '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}')
set -- $var. This did not work so wondering how to process the intermediate results.

Comment: The `> $ERC.result` should have been ` > $i.result`.  Sorry about that.  Making an edit now.

Comment: yeah I figured that piece the issue I am trying to fix though is that the averages it was calculating for all the requests is always shown as 0, like below. Although I am able to get the result of each individual request as a separate file but I wanted the averages of say 10 or 50 request for example :                                                average time connect: 0
average time start: 0
average Totaltime taken: 0

Comment: Post your *.results file underneath your code.  It's really a matter of summing them up using an awk script that reads all the results files in sequentially.  Something like `awk '{sum += $0} END { print sum}' *.result` executed after the `wait`.